# iOS Swift & CoreLocation - Extract X and Y coordinate from CLLocationCoordinate2D into separate variables

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Looking into converting a CLLocationCoordinate2D into two doubles for the longitude and latitude coordinate, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @david mentioned you should always show some code of what you have tried and what is the current setup, but as this is your first question on stackoverflow, il try to answer this one time.

The CLLocationCoordinate2D already has latitude and longitude as doubles.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.first { return }
    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = location.coordinate
    let latitude = location.latitude // Already a double
    let longitude = location.longitude // Already a double
}
```